# Convert column to date time in update stratement

Tags: sql, datetime, casting, dateadd

I need to convert the column `Idx20` to datetime in the format of `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.mmm`.

Please help I've tried to use Cast but it didn't work.

```
UPDATE SMS
SET 
SMS.Idx15 = DEL.Idx4,
SMS.Idx16 = DEL.Idx5,
SMS.Idx20 = DATEADD(HH,-1, DEL.Idx7)
FROM idmsSMSOutBox SMS
INNER JOIN idmsSMSDelivery DEL
ON RIGHT(SMS.Idx3,8) = DEL.Idx3
WHERE 
SMS.Idx15 = 'Delivering'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Column Idx20's data type?

Comment: Also some typical values of Idx20.

Comment: "but it didn't work" is not very helpful, how did you try it, and why didn't it work (error, unexpected values)?

Comment: Also, your question suggests `Idx20` is not currently a `datetime` column. In that case you'd need an `alter` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are trying to change column in date-time format, you should have used ALTER command first for this change.

So instead of convert it every time optimal solution will be to set its datatype to date-time.

```
ALTER TABLE  `table_name` CHANGE  `From Date`  `From Date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: That's a pretty drastic move for the sake of one query.  How do you know that it won't break other applications querying that table.  Hence the downvote.

Comment: @DanBracuk It is drastic, it is also what OP asked for.